# how to redirect links specified as [google](www.google.com.au) in CSS

Tags: hyperlink

The url link which has [google](https://www.google.com) redirects to google page but the url with link googledoes not load the google page.How can I redirect such links in markdown?

Answer (score 0):

A link without specific protocol will navigate relative to the current path. So if you click a link with `href="www.google.com"` on the page `http://example.com` you will get to `http://example.com/www.google.com`. To prevent that, either specify a protocol (http, https) or automatically use the current protocol with to slashes:

```
<a href="//www.google.com">google</a>
```